# Looping through jsonp object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been looking for a week now and I can't find an answer for this situation.

I request data through jsonp.

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "http://www.domain.com/app/loadFeedsApp.php", 
  sync: true,                 
  contentType: "application/json", 
  dataType: 'jsonp',                
  success: function(data) {                     
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

In my server side i sent info like this:

```
$jarr = array();
$af = 0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    $html = array("Appfeed".$af."" => array(
        "cnty" => stripcslashes($row['cnty']),
        "feed" => stripslashes($row['feed']),
        "feedId" => stripslashes($row['feedId']),
        "nickname" => stripslashes($row['nickname']),
        "state" => str_replace("\r\n",'', $row['state']),
        "date" => date("d/m/y", strtotime($row['date'])))               
    ); 
array_push($jarr, $html);    
$af++;
}
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($jarr) . ');';
```

And it returns the data:

```
jQuery21007744578921701759_1395250905357({
"Appfeed0":
{
"cnty":"MEXICO",
"feed":"text",
"feedId":"201",
"nickname":"chaparra",
"state":"Tamaulipas",
"date":"27\/02\/14"
}
});

jQuery21007744578921701759_1395250905357({
"Appfeed1":
{
" cnty ":"MEXICO",
"feed":"text ",
"feedsId":"198",
"nickname":"estudiante",
" state ":"Tamaulipas",
"date":"26\/02\/14"
}
});

jQuery21007744578921701759_1395250905357({
"Appfeed2":
{
" cnty ":"MEXICO",
"feed":"text ",
"feedsId":"197",
"nickname":"el roger",
" state ":"Tamaulipas",
"date":"26\/02\/14"
}
});
```

But when I try to loop through this in java script It just shows the last feed (Appfeed2). Also in when I print the data in console.log(). It looks like just received the last feed too.

```
Object {Appfeed2: Object}
1.  Appfeed2: Object
1.  state: "Tamaulipas"
2.  date: "26/02/14"
3.  feed: "Ayer fui a sacar mi licencia, sin saber manejar, no hice fila y solo me costo 200 pesos mas. Creo que sere taxista "
4.  feedId: "197"
5.  nickname: "el roger"
6.  cnty: "MEXICO"
7.  __proto__: Object
2.  __proto__: Object
```

Any ideas? I was thinking about the way jsonp is returning the data, so I tried with square brackets, with and w/o the get callback, but it fails.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are calling `echo`more than once in your PHP code.  You can't do that with a JSON(P) response.  You need to create the array you want, then call `echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');';` ***once*** at the end of your code.

Comment: What is `sync: true,` for? if you meant `async: false` jsonp requests can't be synchronous.

Comment: Also, `contentType: "application/json",` is *incorrect* here.  That option sets the `Content-type` of the *request* body, it makes no sense here.  P.S. Why do you have `dataType: "jsonp",` twice?

Comment: Thank you for pointing the errors on the code, I guess i've been trying so many things that i lost focus on what I published.

Comment: I update the php code with the array that i create and im echoing. Thank you for your help

Comment: @corr: You are doing the `echo` *inside* the `while` loop.  Don't do that.  Add `$html` to an array and do the `echo` *outside* the loop.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I just did that and the same results I create an array before the while loop and pushed the $html into it.

Comment: @corr: The issue here is that you are `echo`ing `jQuery21007744578921701759_1395250905357({//data})` multiple times.  Can you show us the code and/or the output for when you pushed `$html` into an array?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, My bad, I omit to echo the new array instead. The code I published is working, now i Just have to loop through the result, because it is just showing "undefined". I really appreciate your help and patience

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` show?  That will help you loop over it.    What do you see as the full response?

Comment: It shows three objects: 
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object, and inside each object it shows the the Appfeed object/array

Comment: @corr: Then just loop over the array and then read the `AppfeedX` property of the object.  Or, instead of doing `array_push($jarr, $html);`, do `$jarr["Appfeed".$af] = array( //... );`, then you'll have a object with 3 properties.

Comment: Oh! all right! I see, the second option its simpler. Thank u again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that in your PHP code, you are only echoing out the JSON(P) *once* after the loop finishes.  You need to build the array you want then echo it out at the end.

```
$jarr = array();
$af = 0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    $jarr["Appfeed".$af] = array(
        "cnty" => stripcslashes($row['cnty']),
        "feed" => stripslashes($row['feed']),
        "feedId" => stripslashes($row['feedId']),
        "nickname" => stripslashes($row['nickname']),
        "state" => str_replace("\r\n",'', $row['state']),
        "date" => date("d/m/y", strtotime($row['date'])))               
    );  
    $af++;
}
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($jarr) . ');';
```

P.S. Your AJAX call has a few too many options:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://www.domain.com/app/loadFeedsApp.php",                
    success: function(data) {                     
        $.each(data, function(i, v){
            console.log(i);
            console.log(v);
        });
    }
});
```